# Make pgfplot load data automatically

Tags: pgfplots

I have a (hopefully) nice pgfplot (If you have any optimization suggestions towards the layout, don't hesitate to tell me :) ), which I will be using repeatedly. Therefore I would like to create a new command that is only fed with the data and produces the pgfplot automatically.
The data to be fed are the values of each point plus the values of the confidence intervals. All the rest is supposed to stay the same. I can manage to create a new command where I put each value in question in a {} and put this into the code of the pgfplot - however this is not a nice solution. A more beautiful solution would be to enter the data in one {} and separate the individual entries with spaces.
E.g:

```
\makemypgfplot{
4 3 2.5
5 4 2
7 3 2.5
...
}
```

And this as the corresponding pgfplot:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz} %<-- pgfplots loads TiKZ
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{CG}{RGB}{127, 127, 127}
\definecolor{MC}{RGB}{23, 110, 178}
\definecolor{TV}{RGB}{208, 43, 139}
\definecolor{BP}{RGB}{27, 175, 147}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines=left,
        xlabel= , xmin=0.5, xmax=3.5,
        ylabel=Metacognition,
        axis line style={-},
        xtick = {1,2,3},
        xticklabels = {$t_1$,$t_2$,$t_3$},
        legend style={at={(axis cs:3.8,2)},anchor=south west,font=\small,mark size=2pt}
    ]

    \addplot[ 
        smooth,
        thick,
        solid,
        mark=*,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        color=CG,
        mark options=solid,
        error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
        error bar style={solid},
    ] plot coordinates {
             (0.91,     4)+=(0, 3)-=(0,     2.5)
             (1.91,     5)+=(0, 4)-=(0,     2)
             (2.91,     7)+=(0, 3)-=(0,     2.5)
    };
    \addlegendentry{CG}

    \addplot[smooth,
             thick,
             dashed,
             color=MC,
             mark=square*,
             mark options=solid,
             error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
             error bar style={solid},
    ] plot coordinates {
             (0.97,     1)+=(0, 3)-=(0,     2.5)
             (1.97,     2)+=(0, 4)-=(0,     2)
             (2.97,     4)+=(0, 3)-=(0,     2.5)
    };
    \addlegendentry{MC}

    \addplot[smooth,
             thick,
             dotted,
             color=TV,
             mark=diamond*,
             mark size=3pt,
             mark options=solid,
             error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
             error bar style={solid},
    ] plot coordinates {
             (1.03,     2)+=(0, 3)-=(0,     2.5)
             (2.03,     5)+=(0, 4)-=(0,     2)
             (3.03,     3)+=(0, 3)-=(0,     2.5)
    };
    \addlegendentry{TV}

    \addplot[smooth,
             thick,
             dashdotted,
             color=BP,
             mark=triangle*,
             mark size=3pt,
             mark options=solid,
             error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
             error bar style={solid},
    ] plot coordinates {
             (1.07,     2.4)+=(0,   3)-=(0,     2.5)
             (2.07,     3.1)+=(0,   4)-=(0,     2)
             (3.07,     1.1)+=(0,   3)-=(0,     2.5)
    };
    \addlegendentry{BP}        


    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I struggle to make the new command recognize the individual values. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you for any ideas you might have!
Mil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is the solution I came up myself. It is not very pretty, but it solves the problem I presented very smoothly. This solution also has the positive side effect that it is always clear which group a line of variables belongs to.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz} %<-- pgfplots loads TiKZ
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{CG}{RGB}{127, 127, 127}
\definecolor{MC}{RGB}{23, 110, 178}
\definecolor{TV}{RGB}{208, 43, 139}
\definecolor{BP}{RGB}{27, 175, 147}
\pgfplotsset{%compat=1.9,
             width=6cm,
             height=6cm,
             scale only axis,
             axis lines=left,
             xlabel= , xmin=0.5, xmax=3.5,
             ylabel=Caption,
             ylabel style={yshift=-0.4cm},
             axis line style={-},
             xtick = {1,2,3},
             xticklabels = {$t_1$,$t_2$,$t_3$},
             legend style={at={(axis cs:3.8,2)},anchor=south west,font=\small},
             x tick label style={major tick length=3pt},
             xtick align=inside,
             ytick align=outside}


\newcommand{\plotCG}[9]{
    \addplot[ 
        smooth,
        thick,
        solid,
        mark=*,
        mark size=2.5pt,
        color=CG,
        mark options=solid,
        error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
        error bar style={solid},
    ] plot coordinates {
             (0.91,     #1)+=(0, #2)-=(0,     #3)
             (1.91,     #4)+=(0, #5)-=(0,     #6)
             (2.91,     #7)+=(0, #8)-=(0,     #9)
    };
    \addlegendentry{CG}
    }

\newcommand{\plotMC}[9]{
    \addplot[smooth,
             thick,
             dashed,
             color=MC,
             mark=square*,
             mark options=solid,
             error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
             error bar style={solid},
    ] plot coordinates {
             (0.97,     #1)+=(0, #2)-=(0,     #3)
             (1.97,     #4)+=(0, #5)-=(0,     #6)
             (2.97,     #7)+=(0, #8)-=(0,     #9)
    };
    \addlegendentry{MC}   
    }

\newcommand{\plotTV}[9]{  
    \addplot[smooth,
             thick,
             dotted,
             color=TV,
             mark=diamond*,
             mark size=3pt,
             mark options=solid,
             error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
             error bar style={solid},
    ] plot coordinates {
             (1.03,     #1)+=(0, #2)-=(0,     #3)
             (2.03,     #4)+=(0, #5)-=(0,     #6)
             (3.03,     #7)+=(0, #8)-=(0,     #9)
    };
    \addlegendentry{TV}
    }

\newcommand{\plotBP}[9]{      
    \addplot[smooth,
             thick,
             dashdotted,
             color=BP,
             mark=triangle*,
             mark size=3pt,
             mark options=solid,
             error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,
             error bar style={solid},
    ] plot coordinates {
             (1.07,     #1)+=(0,   #2)-=(0,     #3)
             (2.07,     #4)+=(0,   #5)-=(0,     #6)
             (3.07,     #7)+=(0,   #8)-=(0,     #9)
    };
    \addlegendentry{BP}  
    }



\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
    \begin{axis}[ylabel=Metacognition]
    \plotCG{4}{3}{2.5}{5}{4}{2}{7}{3}{2.5}  
    \plotMC{1}{3}{2.5}{2}{4}{2}{4}{3}{2.5}  
    \plotTV{2}{3}{2.5}{5}{4}{2}{3}{3}{2.5}  
    \plotBP{2.4}{3}{2.5}{3.1}{4}{2}{1.1}{3}{2.5}  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
    \begin{axis}[ylabel=Motivation]
    \plotCG{3}{3}{2.5}{3}{4}{2}{4}{3}{2.5}  
    \plotMC{4}{3}{2.5}{4}{4}{2}{4}{3}{2.5}  
    \plotTV{2}{3}{2.5}{2}{4}{2}{3}{3}{2.5}  
    \plotBP{5}{3}{2.5}{4}{4}{2}{3}{3}{2.5}  
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kjell Magne Fauske has a published a macro for drawing line plots on [TeXample.com](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/weather-stations-data/). He defines his data lines in an external txt-document. (Actually he stores them in a variable and calls the variable in his macro.) Creating the txt-document can easily be done with a usual text editor using replacements.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it doesn't really suit the needs outlined above as not big datalines have to be important but only these selected 3*4*3 values. Creating a temporary variable for each of them seems to be a bit exaggerated. ;)